# SQL strings added more than once for: tablename

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm bootstrapping a database using [hibernate-maven-plugin](http://juplo.de/hibernate-maven-plugin/), using models that it scans in the maven module it's executed in.

Unfortunately, it stops when hibernate throws this:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: SQL strings added more than once for: reference_data_source.UK-UK_9ec6wdvyj3mjagiptcnrq2txv
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.checkExportIdentifier(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:299)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:255)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:199)
```

So, I have two persistence units, and some tables exists in both. Hibernate seems to interpret this like the same table though, so when it tries to store the same index, but for another schema, it fails thinking it is a duplicate. Their code can be found [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f82dd465b124f00df58a30a1faf9d0d0d2287685/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/schema/internal/SchemaCreatorImpl.java).

I'm not sure how to approach this, anyway to configure hibernate hbm2ddl to keep track of these different peristence units?

This is the configuration for the hibernate-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <detail>true</detail>
        <persistenceUnit>mainPersistenceUnit</persistenceUnit>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</dialect>
        <force>true</force>
        <url><![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost/auto_bootstrap_schema]]></url>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>pass</password>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. The reason in my case was that I had three entities starting with same prefix name and a OneToMany relation to the each more specialized one:

```
Person
PersonCard
PersonCardLayout
```

Renaming my model to this solved my problem:

```
Person
Card
Layout
```

This seems to be a bug in Hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

i have the same problem, looks like a bug in:
org.hibernate.mapping.UniqueKey#getExportIdentifier

```
@Override
public String getExportIdentifier() {
    return StringHelper.qualify( getTable().getName(), "UK-" + getName() );
}
```

because the identifier was build only from table name but without schema/catalog of the table.

Therefore, if you have to entities with same table name but different schema and in these entities two properties with same name and "unique = true" you will drop into the bug.

Comment: Very interesting. I have since asking the question left that company and can't confirm on that software, we went down the one persistence route, that however I couldn't accept ere as a solution, so your findings helps this question's thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution to this is to make use of @Table.

For example:

@Table(name="PERSON")

This happened to me when I had two classes representing two entities (@Entity) as follows:

@Entity
public class User {...}

@Entity
public class UserRoles {...}

I fixed this error by specifying the table name as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {...}
```

And:

```
@Table(name="USER_ROLES")
@Entity
public class UserRoles {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same as what I ran into, but I had the same error issue with base class marked with @Entity annotation: changing to @MappedSuperclass removed the error.

Good Luck,
Ray